# Android-facebook chat client using xmpp

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

Am using asmack to login to the facebook for chatting using my apikey and access token ! But the login is failing with the following exception

"SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM: " I want to know from where i can get a properly working "extends SASLMechanism" class to do it and also help me to login currently am using the following class
[custom](http://community.igniterealtime.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/220711-15693/SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.java.zip)  . And for making the login :--

```
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",     SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);     
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);     
            connection.connect(); 
            connection.login(facebook.getAppId(), facebook.getAccessToken());
```

// But it's not working

Comment: Gopala have u got the solution for this question

Answer (score 1):

I tested this one and it worked for me .

First of all Edit your SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class . Copy and paste this code .

```
package com.facebook.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;

public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              accessToken        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            String composedResponse =
                "method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") +
                        "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8") +
                        "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8") +
                        "&api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") +
                        "&call_id=0" +
                        "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");
            response = composedResponse.getBytes();
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Then use this method in your activity class from where you want to login to facebook

```
private void LoginToFaceBook(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());




        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

Comment: then where we have to add the username and password

Comment: You will need to enter access token in this line .
xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());

Comment: manually i need to enter accesstoken ah dude,first is this i need to login facebook then i have to use this code ah

Comment: ,i got accesstoken and apikey for login,its showing these error 03-28 07:07:33.506: W/System.err(8440): java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
what is this one,how to solve

Comment: i used ur code,its shows some error like this NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found

Comment: i solved that error now how to get only only available friends and how to chat

Comment: for ex i am giving like this have to enter to place in text and then message and then click send,while clicking send its throwing NPE in this line   connection.sendPacket(msg); to i am writing like this xxx@chat.facebook.com

Comment: by calling methods me/friends, check facebook api documentation for further details.

Comment: its having the ssl trust problem you dont have that code